# How does Gmail prevent overlap for elements that use absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, layout, gmail, positioning

I've recently begun my journey of learning CSS, and have been studying Gmail's design, as I've always been curious of just how Gmail works.

One problem that I can't seem to figure out is just how Gmail seemingly gets an absolutely positioned div to act like it's still part of the flow. Here's the div I'm referring to:

[image]

The computed style of that div is as follows:
[image]

The issue is, when the browser width decreases, I would think that this absolutely positioned div would overlap with the search form directly to the left of it. Instead, it seems to compact the search form as if it were still part of the flow. I checked the search form and other elements around it for possible margins or padding that might be keeping it from overlapping, but my untrained eye has found nothing.

Here's to hoping a more experienced CSS and Gmail user could take a look at the Gmail DOM tree and explain this to me.
Cheers!

Comment: Have you disabled Javascript?

Comment: Knowing how things work is great, but I wouldn't suggest ever treating Google's code as an example of how to do something well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript for that. You can bind to the resize event of the window object and recalculate and reposition your elements when the browser is resized.

In plain javascript:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // recalculate
};
```

In jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    // recalculate
});
```

Another option is to have a position:relative on the container surrounding the absolutely positioned elements. If that relative container resizes with the browser window then the absolute containers inside it will move with it.

Comment: Thanks Rob, could you point me to the element where I can find this event listener?

Comment: Great clarification Rob. Any opinions on using javascript for this purpose vs. using the second option you provided involving absolute position inside relative position? Do you think one way is necessarily better?

Comment: It really depends on the complexity of the layout. If you can do it with css, that's usually the better option because it's faster and works for users that have javascript disabled.